# Conditionally Including css in C# ASP.net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, webforms

I am trying to conditionally include a css file depending on what browser the user is using.  And I've been able to get it to work one way but not the way I want because it will require an extra style sheet.   The way that works, in my Site.Master file I include a style sheet for ie8.

```
<link href="~/Styles/ie8.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then in Site.Master.cs in the `Page_Load` function.

```
    if (!(browser.Type == "IE8" ||
        browser.Type == "IE7" ||
        browser.Type == "IE6" ||
        browser.Type == "IE5"))
    {
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
            "<link rel=\" stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + ResolveUrl("~/Styles/ie.css") + "\" />"));
    }
```

This works and the css is correct and using developer tools and compatibility in ie10 I can see it includes the correct css.  But If I change my code to what should be equivalent.  It doesn't work.  Site.Master:

```
<link href="~/Styles/ie.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Site.Master.cs

```
    if ((browser.Type == "IE8" ||
        browser.Type == "IE7" ||
        browser.Type == "IE6" ||
        browser.Type == "IE5"))
    {
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
            "<link rel=\" stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + ResolveUrl("~/Styles/ie8.css") + "\" />"));
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint at `Page.Header.Controls.Add` I can see the function is getting called when in compatibility mode in ie10.  But then when I go to dev tools and look for elements that use classes defined in ie8.css they aren't there like it was never included.  What is going on here?

Comment: Why do you need to use dev tools and breakpoints to see if the stylesheet was included? Just view source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for IE serverside, you should use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="ie8.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link href="ie.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: I've seen suggestions for that but I never could get them working.  What I saw what this http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ .  When I entered it into `<!--[if lte IE 8]> <![endif]-->` Visual studio seems to think it is a comment.  Unless I am entering it into the incorrect place.  I rather do it client side if I could get that working.

Comment: If you aren't between the `head` tags (or a ContentPlaceHolder that is in the `head`) then you are in the wrong place. It should work fine in VS.

Comment: It works.  I like this solution better, despite it not answering the question.  What is completely baffling is why would the label it as a comment when it actually does something.  That is not a comment if it has an effect on the program.  And why the server side doesn't work makes no sense either.

Comment: It _is_ a comment. Only the dirty ones from Redmond recognize these statements. That's why they're called "**conditional** comments".

Comment: hi @DiegoNolan, I cant still make it work. I have added it like this on my master <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Shared/Header.ascx" TagName="Header" TagPrefix="Admin" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Shared/Footer.ascx" TagName="Footer" TagPrefix="Admin" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="Shared/Styles/ie.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body> Can you let me know how you fixed it?